# Install Craft on VPS with centos 7 and vestacp

Tags: installation

I downloading craft with Composer, but when i move on example.com/index.php?p=admin nothing happens. In the logs:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/User/web/example.com/vendor/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/User/web/example.com/public_html:/home/User/tmp) in /home/User/web/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 11
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/User/web/example.com/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/User/web/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 11
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/User/web/example.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/User/web/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 11
```

Comment: I solved this problem, but I do not know if it's safe. In /home/User/conf/web/example.com.httpd.conf in string php_admin_value open_basedir /home/User/web/example.com/public_html:/home/Userl/tmp replace on php_admin_value open_basedir /home/User/web/example.com:/home/Userl/tmp

Comment: Seems like a perfectly valid solution to me... would you mind adding it as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. In /home/User/conf/web/example.com.httpd.conf in string

```
php_admin_value open_basedir/home/User/web/example.com/public_html:/home/Userl/tmp
```

replace on

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /home/User/web/example.com:/home/Userl/tmp
```